# "Сделать подарок", "подарить подарок", "преподнести подарок"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно: "сделать подарок", "подарить подарок", "преподнести подарок"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подарить подарок - это тавтологическая конструкция. Лучше "сделать подарок" (больше подходит для условий разговорной речи) или "преподнести подарок" (книжная речь, официально-деловой стиль)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В основе подарка находится дар(а). Дар(а) - сложная конструкция и в глубокой древности сложилось из да и ра. Каждая из морфем (лексем,- извините) является названием понятия. Ра это - солнце (свет, блистательность, сверкательность, а да это - предоставление (не буду отвлекаться на доказательства). Возможно, в древности слово звучало иначе, но сложено оно выло из этих двух понятий. Смысл слова был, вероятнее всего, - предоставление жизни плененным врагам, или предоставление воли и прав рабам. Если вдуматься, то можно себе это ясно представить. С годами слово дар приобрело современное звучание и значение, но так или иначе, оно уже содержит в себе сказуемое. Поэтому дополнительное сказуемое здесь неуместно.
Правильно говорить " подарить (что-то)". Между прочим, "сделать подарок" правомерно по отношению к самому подарку, который вы собираетесь сделать своими руками.

Comment: Откуда информация? Как звучало в древности, предположить можно, вот, например, так: даръ.